# fo-dicom DicomTag.ModalitiesInStudy

Tags: fo-dicom

How can I get all String Values DicomTag.ModalitiesInStudy
Current command that i use returns only one Modality from 3 :
response.Dataset.[Get](Of String)(DicomTag.ModalitiesInStudy)
[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFe5L.png)
Thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that Visual Basic you are using?

In C#, to get the array of modalities, simply use:

```
string[] modalities = response.Dataset.Get<string[]>(DicomTag.ModalitiesInStudy);
```

**UPDATE** VB.NET formulation, according to @Muttleskovic's comment below:

```
Dim ModalityStrings() As String = response.Dataset.[Get](Of String())(DicomTag.ModalitiesInStudy)
```

Comment: I've tried something like that, but was receiving syntax error. It's very possible that it's written different in VB. In the mean time found a work around : I'me getting the count 1st then read DicomTag.ModalitiesInStudy with index id.Dim x As Integer = Int(responsef.Dataset.[Get](Of String)(DicomTag.ModalitiesInStudy).Count)
Dim xx As String = responsef.Dataset.[Get](Of String)(DicomTag.ModalitiesInStudy, i)

Comment: I've tried one more time and seems to work like a charm now , Thank. Visual Basic : Dim ModalityStrings() As String = response.Dataset.[Get](Of String())(DicomTag.ModalitiesInStudy) Btw aren't you the one of the owners of fo-dicom ? I notice you have same avatar as Cureos from nuget. If so , great work, thank a lot